# Can't Get Floated Items To Exceed Width Of Parent

Tags: css

I cannot get the desired effect on a CSS only news ticker. If I use position absolute, the links only show up once the with of the link has cleared. If I use position relative, I get the desired effect(marquee), but the items break down to a second row if the number of items exceed the width of the parent.

I've tried all sorts of things to get it to work with `position:relative`. I even tried `display:inline-block; white-space:nowrap;`.

How can I keep the floated items to one row, regardless of parent width?

HTML

```
Position Absolute<br>
<div id="news-ticker-1" class="marquee-1">
    <span class="news-label">News</span>
    <div class="overflow">
    <a class="item" href="#">First Link</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Second Link</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Third Link</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Fourth Link</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Fifth Link</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Sixth Link</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Seventh Link</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Eighth Link</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Ninth Link</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Tenth Link</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Eleventh Link</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Twelfth Link</a>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
Position Relative
<div id="news-ticker-2" class="marquee-2">
    <span class="news-label">News</span>
    <div class="overflow">
    <a class="item" href="#">First Link</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Second Link</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Third Link</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Fourth Link</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Fifth Link</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Sixth Link</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Seventh Link</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Eighth Link</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Ninth Link</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Tenth Link</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Eleventh Link</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Twelfth Link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.marquee-1 {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.marquee-1 .overflow {
    position: absolute;
    animation-name: marquee-1;
    animation-duration: 40s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.marquee-1:hover .overflow {
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
.marquee-1 .item {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
@keyframes marquee-1 {
    from {
        left: 100%;
    }
    to {
        left: -200%;
    }
}
#news-ticker-1 {
    background: rgba(190, 128, 255, 0.6);
    border-right: 3px solid #BE80FF;
    height: 60px;
}
#news-ticker-1 .news-label {
    background: #BE80FF;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 60px;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    color: #fff;
}
#news-ticker-1 a {
    line-height: 60px;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    color: #fff;
}
#news-ticker-1 a:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
#news-ticker-1 a:first-child {
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}




.marquee-2 {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.marquee-2 .overflow {
    position: relative;
    animation-name: marquee-2;
    animation-duration: 40s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.marquee-2:hover .overflow {
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
.marquee-2 .item {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
@keyframes marquee-2 {
    from {
        left: 100%;
    }
    to {
        left: -200%;
    }
}
#news-ticker-2 {
    background: rgba(190, 128, 255, 0.6);
    border-right: 3px solid #BE80FF;
    height: 60px;
}
#news-ticker-2 .news-label {
    background: #BE80FF;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 60px;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    color: #fff;
}
#news-ticker-2 a {
    line-height: 60px;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    color: #fff;
}
#news-ticker-2 a:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
#news-ticker-2 a:first-child {
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/n6a5uLao/

NOTE: code includes both examples from fiddle. By observing the fiddle, it will better explain the issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on your **Position Relative** here:

```
.marquee-2 .item {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

change to:

```
.marquee-2 .item {
    display: table-cell;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

#### Snippet:

```css
.marquee-2 {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.marquee-2 .overflow {
    position: relative;
    animation-name: marquee-2;
    animation-duration: 40s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.marquee-2:hover .overflow {
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
.marquee-2 .item {
    display: table-cell;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
@keyframes marquee-2 {
    from {
        left: 100%;
    }
    to {
        left: -200%;
    }
}
#news-ticker-2 {
    background: rgba(190, 128, 255, 0.6);
    border-right: 3px solid #BE80FF;
    height: 60px;
}
#news-ticker-2 .news-label {
    background: #BE80FF;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 60px;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    color: #fff;
}
#news-ticker-2 a {
    line-height: 60px;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    color: #fff;
}
#news-ticker-2 a:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
#news-ticker-2 a:first-child {
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
Position Relative
<div id="news-ticker-2" class="marquee-2">
    <span class="news-label">News</span>
    <div class="overflow">
    <a class="item" href="#">First Link</a>
 <a class="item" href="#">Second Link</a>
 <a class="item" href="#">Third Link</a>
 <a class="item" href="#">Fourth Link</a>
 <a class="item" href="#">Fifth Link</a>
 <a class="item" href="#">Sixth Link</a>
 <a class="item" href="#">Seventh Link</a>
 <a class="item" href="#">Eighth Link</a>
 <a class="item" href="#">Ninth Link</a>
 <a class="item" href="#">Tenth Link</a>
 <a class="item" href="#">Eleventh Link</a>
 <a class="item" href="#">Twelfth Link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just add `white-space: nowrap;` and the answer is complete

Comment: Genius. I didn't think to use display:table-cell. I added display:table to the parent element though to be more semantic.